# Automatically typed exports based on file structure in typescript

Tags: typescript, directory-structure

I am wondering if is it possible to tell typescript that all files in specific folder must export specific typed value

For example I have folder `models` and every file in that folder must export object with type `Model`.

I can just use `as` keyword in each model file

```js
import { Model } from 'types';

export default {
  ...
} as Model;
```

but is there a way to make typescript automatically type those files to get auto completion without need to importing `Model` type and asserting it?

```js
export default {
  ...
}
```

It's not a big deal, I'm just curious if such a thing is possible, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can define file export with

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

I doubt that would enforce the type of work on `.ts` files

---

I would recommend ensuring the correct export type by using a typechecking function

```
import {ensureModel} from '...'
export default ensureModel({
   modelId: 123
})
```

```
export function ensureModel<T extends Model>(v: T): T { return v }
```

optionally with

```
import {ensureModel} from '...'
export default ensureModel({
   modelId: 123 as const
}) // <-- export Model & {modelId: 123}
```

```
import {ensureModel} from '...'
export default ensureModel({
   modelId: 123
} as const) // <-- export Model & {modelId: 123, ...}
```

to freese constants

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was trying to use module declaration, but as you said, it doesn't work the way I wanted to, also thanks for the alternative solution, looks better than type assertion